# Footer to postion itself on bottom of HTML section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a one page website. I have created 3 HTML sections and in the sections I have divs containing all of the content. The sections each resize themselves to the size of the screen and I have used JQuery to do this. Inside of the sections I would like to have a footer at the very bottom of the section but this is proving difficult. I have tried putting containers inside of each section and setting a min-height of 100% and then placing the footer inside but this does not work. I have provided some links. I would really appreciate some help.

The website is at [www.test.tagwebsites.com.au](http://www.test.tagwebsites.com.au).
    Javascript

```
<script>
function newsize() {
var wide = $(window).width();
var high = $(window).height();
$("section").width(wide).height(high);
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<section>
<div id="portfolio">
<span id="holder"></span>

        <table border="0" id="gallery">
        <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.raydz.com.au" target="new"><img src="images/raydz.png" alt="raydz website" /></a></td>
        <td><img src="images/gozzy.png" alt="gozzy website" title="Under construction"/></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.thevanfromhoian.com.au" target="new"><img src="images/hoian.png" alt="hoian website" title="The van from Hoi An" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.buxtongeneralstore.com.au" target="new"><img src="images/buxton.png" alt="buxton website" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://invest.edwardhinds.com.au" target="new"><img src="images/invest.png" alt="invest website" /></a></td>
        <td><img src="images/edward.png" alt="edward website" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="images/hanson.png" alt="hanson website" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/upskilled.png" alt="upskilled website" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/edwards.png" alt="edward hinds website" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
            <div id="foliofooter" class="foot">
            <p>These are just some of the pages we have developed</p>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.foot{display:block;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#F33;
position:relative; 
bottom:0px;
clear:both;
}

#gallery{display:block;
clear:both;
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
min-height:100%;
}

#portfolio{display:block;
clear:both;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: So were you attempting to place the footer at the bottom of the webpage, or just a footer area at the bottom of **each** section? In the latter case, what's the code structure for the sections? Are those areas in red background the footers for each section (excluding the navigation menu)? When you said 'this does not work', what do you mean exactly? I do see them on the webpage, so they 'work', by definition.

Comment: @Kinburn101 "using `top` and `bottom` will not work for elements which are positioned relatively" - this is incorrect, you can absolutely use `top` and `bottom` for relatively positioned elements - [see w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: @Brett East My mistake. All this time I've always used margins for relatively positioned items!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what is happening, is that your `.foot` class with `bottom: 0px` is positioning your footer at the bottom of the section. But then the browser hits your javascipt and if the window height is bigger than the height of the section, it changes the height of the section - but it leaves the footer behind (i.e. that is where the css first placed it).

You need something in your jquery like this:

```
function newsize() {
  var wide = $(window).width();
  var high = $(window).height();
  $("section").width(wide).height(high);
  $('.foot').css("bottom", "0px");  
}
```

Also, call this function as soon as the page loads, if you don't already.

Remove `bottom: 0px` from  the css for `.foot`

Now you have set the bottom property after the height of the section has been specified.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I just got your post. I decided to start again from scratch. I didn't get to try your suggestion but I know that this is definitely what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build the template again from scratch. This time I started with the sections, added div containers the same width and height as the sections, by using absolute positioning with top of 0 and bottom of 0, and then added the footers using relative positioning. I then added the rest of the content. This solved all of my issues. I must have made a small mistake during the initial build.